# Python Lambda AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension timeout randomly

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I have set up a Python 3.10 Lambda that has attached [Secret Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets_lambda.html) and NO VPC attached.

- The timeout time is 20 seconds
- The execution normally takes 1-3seconds
- All Secret Layer variables aren't set, so the default

I have noticed that randomly (1 in ~10) the execution timeout.

It's mostly the first execution the one that fails.

I have enabled the `PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_LOG_LEVEL` to DEBUG and checked in CloudWatch logs:

```
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:27 PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_LOG_LEVEL is debug. Log level set to debug.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:27 DEBUG PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_CACHE_ENABLED is not present. Cache is enabled by default.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:27 DEBUG PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_CACHE_SIZE is not present. Using default cache size: 1000 objects.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:27 DEBUG SECRETS_MANAGER_TTL is not present. Setting default time-to-live: 5m0s.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:27 DEBUG SSM_PARAMETER_STORE_TTL is not present. Setting default time-to-live: 5m0s.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:27 DEBUG SECRETS_MANAGER_TIMEOUT_MILLIS is not present. Setting default timeout: 0s.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:27 DEBUG SSM_PARAMETER_STORE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS is not present. Setting default timeout: 0s.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:27 DEBUG PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_MAX_CONNECTIONS is not present. Setting default value: 3.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:27 DEBUG PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_HTTP_PORT is not present. Setting default port: 2773.
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:27 INFO Systems Manager Parameter Store and Secrets Manager Lambda Extension 1.0.103
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:27 DEBUG Creating a new cache with size 1000
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:27 INFO Serving on port 2773
EXTENSION   Name: AWSParametersAndSecretsLambdaExtension    State: Ready    Events: [INVOKE, SHUTDOWN]
START RequestId: 2bdcca16-5b8b-449d---- Version: $LATEST
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:51 INFO ready to serve traffic
[AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:15:51 DEBUG Caching secret with key /secretsmanager/get?secretId=arn:aws:secretsmanager:.....
2023-06-13T14:15:57.299Z 2bdcca16-5b8b-449d---- Task timed out after 30.08 seconds

END RequestId: 2bdcca16-5b8b-449d----
REPORT RequestId: 2bdcca16-5b8b-449d----    Duration: 30075.25 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms   Memory Size: 160 MB Max Memory Used: 122 MB 
XRAY TraceId: 1-648879ff-4cf918900c6e2df----    SegmentId: 2584b0c77f85---  Sampled: true
```

Normally after the `DEBUG Caching secret with key /secretsmanager...` line, the source code is executed and the function succeds.
But in some cases the source code doesn't even start , so I can't write any logs inside because it doesn't get there

Any help is appreacited,

EDIT:
Increased time to 1m and looks like the request to secret manager is just too slow.
The problem is that ApiGateway timeouts at 30s, so it fails

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   timestamp   |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|---------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2023-06-13T11:23:36.533-03:00 | INIT_START Runtime Version: python:3.9.v23 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2::runtime:bf3c2cf12ad277455c37                                                                                                                              
| 2023-06-13T11:23:36.533-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:36 PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_LOG_LEVEL is debug. Log level set to debug.                                                                                                          
| 2023-06-13T11:23:36.533-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:36 DEBUG PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_CACHE_ENABLED is not present. Cache is enabled by default.                                                                                     
| 2023-06-13T11:23:36.533-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:36 DEBUG PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_CACHE_SIZE is not present. Using default cache size: 1000 objects.                                                                             
| 2023-06-13T11:23:36.533-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:36 DEBUG SECRETS_MANAGER_TTL is not present. Setting default time-to-live: 5m0s.                                                                                                     
| 2023-06-13T11:23:36.533-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:36 DEBUG SSM_PARAMETER_STORE_TTL is not present. Setting default time-to-live: 5m0s.                                                                                                 
| 2023-06-13T11:23:36.533-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:36 DEBUG SECRETS_MANAGER_TIMEOUT_MILLIS is not present. Setting default timeout: 0s.                                                                                                 
| 2023-06-13T11:23:36.533-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:36 DEBUG SSM_PARAMETER_STORE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS is not present. Setting default timeout: 0s.                                                                                             
| 2023-06-13T11:23:36.533-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:36 DEBUG PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_MAX_CONNECTIONS is not present. Setting default value: 3.                                                                                      
| 2023-06-13T11:23:36.533-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:36 DEBUG PARAMETERS_SECRETS_EXTENSION_HTTP_PORT is not present. Setting default port: 2773.                                                                                          
| 2023-06-13T11:23:36.533-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:36 INFO Systems Manager Parameter Store and Secrets Manager Lambda Extension 1.0.103                                                                                                 
| 2023-06-13T11:23:36.533-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:36 DEBUG Creating a new cache with size 1000                                                                                                                                         
| 2023-06-13T11:23:38.776-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:36 INFO Serving on port 2773                                                                                                                                                         
| 2023-06-13T11:23:38.778-03:00 | EXTENSION Name: AWSParametersAndSecretsLambdaExtension State: Ready Events: [INVOKE, SHUTDOWN]                                                                                                                                                      
| 2023-06-13T11:23:38.799-03:00 | START RequestId: b1e85fec-aef3-45c1-8486- Version: $LATEST                                                                                                                                                                                          
| 2023-06-13T11:23:39.249-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:38 INFO ready to serve traffic                                                                                                                                                       
| 2023-06-13T11:23:39.249-03:00 | [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/06/13 14:23:39 DEBUG Caching secret with key /secretsmanager...                                                                                                                                  
| 2023-06-13T11:24:13.788-03:00 | ISSUE: TESTTW-76.....
| 2023-06-13T11:24:13.788-03:00 | ISSUE: TESTTW-76.....
| 2023-06-13T11:24:13.788-03:00 | ISSUE: TESTTW-76.....
| 2023-06-13T11:24:13.788-03:00 | ISSUE: TESTTW-76.....
| 2023-06-13T11:24:13.788-03:00 | ISSUE: TESTTW-76.....
| 2023-06-13T11:24:15.560-03:00 | END RequestId: b1e85fec-aef3-45c1-8486-                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| 2023-06-13T11:24:15.560-03:00 | REPORT RequestId: b1e85fec-aef3-45c1-8486- Duration: 36782.12 ms Billed Duration: 36783 ms Memory Size: 160 MB Max Memory Used: 157 MB Init Duration: 2243.76 ms  XRAY TraceId: 1-64887bdd-6e0c2f25704568f90d6 SegmentId: 502be5bc3c57 Sampled: true
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can update the question with your Python code? Also, the logs provided only display the middle section. Could you clarify when the first log entry was created by the lambda function?

Comment: I updated with the full logs.

Comment: Based on the log, it seems that the secrets manager extension responds back within a few seconds (from: 23:36.533 to 23:39.249). I suspect the problem exists somewhere else. Can post a sample code of your lambda function implementation?

Comment: So I started to create log in different parts of the app to show where it hangs and I found that the culprit was a call to `https://api.ipify.org`.

Apparently the api is giving timeouts randomly and this was the reason my Lambda was timing out.

Thank you codeninja for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after  much troubleshooting, found out that the reason was source code giving the timeout

A call to `https://api.ipify.org` was the culprit

Apparently the api isn't working all the time and randomly takes 1s to >1m to answer with the IP